# SQL Server 2008 Stored Proc suddenly returns -1

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I use the following stored procedure from my SQL Server 2008 database to return a value to my C#-Program

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getArticleBelongsToCatsCount] 
@id int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @result int;

   set @result = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM art_in_cat WHERE child_id = @id);
   return @result;
END
```

I use a SQLCommand-Object to call this Stored Procedure

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery()
{
  try
  {
    return _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Logger.instance.ErrorRoutine(e, "Text: " + _command.CommandText);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Till recently, everything works fine. All of a sudden, the stored procedure returned -1. At first, I suspected, that the ExecuteNonQuery-Command would have caused and Exception, but when stepping through the function, it shows that no Exception is thrown and the return value comes directly from return _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

I checked following parameters and they were as expected:
- Connection object was set to the correct database with correct access values
- the parameter for the SP was there and contained the right type, direction and value

Then I checked the SP via SQLManager, I used the same value for the parameter like the one for which my C# brings -1 as result (btw. I checked some more parameter values in my C' program and they ALL returned -1) but in the manager, the SP returns the correct value.

It looks like the call from my C# prog is somehow bugged, but as I don't get any error (it's just the -1 from the SP), I have no idea, where to look for a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of rows affected by an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation, not the return value of a stored procedure. If it was working in the past, is there a possibility that data was being modified by your query?

To get the return value of a stored procedure, add a parameter to your command with ParameterDirection.ReturnValue. After calling ExecuteNonQuery(), that parameter will be populated with the return value of the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: I don't think so. His stored procedure doesn't return a resultset, so ExecuteNonQuery should still be appropriate unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Based on the SP, he should be using `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row of the result set. In this case the value he wants is not in a resultset at all, but is rather the return value of the stored procedure.

Comment: That's really strange. I used the ExecuteNonQuery() and it returned the value of @result. Still, when I execute this in MSSQL-Manager the value in the field "Return Value" is the Expected Value. Anyway, I changed the proc to use an output parameter and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are returning the status of the Count query execution when you really want the value of `COUNT (*)`.

I think it should be like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getArticleBelongsToCatsCount] 
@id int,
@NumberOfRows int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @NumberOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM art_in_cat WHERE child_id = @id;

END
```

Comment: Aren't both commands equal? We use both of them and I haven't noticed a difference.

Comment: corrected answer to show @NumberOfRows as an OUTPUT variable.

Comment: OUtput variable is definitely the right way to go, return should never be used except to tell if the proc was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to
>   perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a
>   database or creating database objects
>   such as tables), or to change the data
>   in a database without using a DataSet
>   by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE
>   statements.
>
> Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns
>   no rows, any output parameters or
>   return values mapped to parameters are
>   populated with data.
>
> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE
>   statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the
>   command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the
>   return value includes the number of
>   rows affected by both the insert or
>   update operation and the number of
>   rows affected by the trigger or
>   triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If
>   a rollback occurs, the return value is
>   also -1.**

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) is probably what you want.

Your SP could then be this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getArticleBelongsToCatsCount] 
@id int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM art_in_cat WHERE child_id = @id
END
```

Answer (score 1):

return _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

should be

return _command.ExecuteScalar();

Reason being that it is a query you are running, a query that returns a single value.  ExecuteNonQuery() assumes there is nothing being returned at all (such as running an UPDATE query).

Comment: ExecuteScalar will return the first record of the first row of the resultset that you are running, NOT the return value of a stored procedure. ExecuteNonQuery() is the appropriate call, but you do need to add a parameter to store the return value.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns a value of -1 for commands that don't affect any rows.  See the documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).  You need to check the value of the output parameter @result.